# How do I add characters to a string immediately before the occurrence of all numbers between the first and last ones in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

**SCENARIO**

I have a program in Java that randomly puts out text as follows:

*1 egg1 chicken and 2 ducks*

*2 cows1 pig1 egg and 2 cats*

*1 hour1 dog1 ostrich 2 cows and 3 chickens*

**QUESTION:**

**How do I add a comma and a space within a string immediately before the occurrence of all numbers between the first and last ones?** That is, how can I format these strings so that these cases look as follows:

*1 egg, 1 chicken and 2 ducks*

*2 cows, 1 pig, 1 egg and 2 cats*

*1 tractor, 1 dog, 1 ostrich, 2 cows and 3 chickens*

As you will see, in each case I:

**WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:**

I already have it successfully handles cases of:

1 object:

*1 cat*

2 objects:

*2 cats*

Variants of Multiple Objects:

*3 cats and 1 ostrich*

and

*1 truck and 6 gnomes*

**What I need to do is:**

1. Identify is a string has 3 or more numbers.
2. If so, skip the first number in the string.
3. Find the next occurring number that is not the last one.
4. Add " ," to it.

I can successfully go through the string and count the numbers it has in it:

```
    // count digits in string
    int digitsInString = 0;
    for (int i = 0, len = concatenatedValue.length(); i < len; i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(concatenatedValue.charAt(i))) {
            digitsInString++;
        }
    }

    // if it only has < 3 digits, no formatting is needed
    if(digitsInString < 3) {
        return concatenatedValue;
    } else {
    //I've got to figure out what goes here
    }
```

Any ideas? I'm writing it now by just splitting the string into a char array, but that seems kind of verbose and amateur. I'd like to maybe do something a little more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "1 hour1 dog1 ostrich 2 cows and 3 chickens";
    String output = input.replaceAll("(?<=[a-z]) ?(?<! and )(\\d+)", ", $1");
    System.out.println(output);
  }
}
```

Returns:

```
1 hour, 1 dog, 1 ostrich, 2 cows and 3 chickens
```

---

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=[a-z])` - Positive lookbehind for a single character in range `a-z`.
- `?` - Match an optional space.
- `(?<! and )` - Negative lookbehind for `and`.
- `(` - Open 1st capture group.

  - `\d+` - Match at least a single digit (double escaped in Java).
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.

We replace with:

- `, $1` - Comma and space literals and whatever is captured in 1st capture group.

See the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/CUvseo/1)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you! 

If it isn't too much trouble, can I ask you to explain the regex to me? I always get confused when I see it. I can understand some of it but a step by step explanation would make me happy (again, if you have time).